# One user with more than one mail on ASP.NET Membership Provider

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, membership-provider

i need to know this.. in the asp.net membership provider, it is possible to create a user with more than one mail?
The thing is that i want in my page (ASP.NET MVC 3) the users can have various emails to login.

It's this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't. Use Membership Profile provider to associate additional information with each user account.

Comment: @sergei - you should post this as an answer instead of a comment.  it's better than the other answers posted which suggest creating a whole custom membership provider when a profile will suffice

Comment: @Robert Levy - Thanks. Took your advice. Thought this was minor enough where a comment would suffice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Membership Provider is limited to 1 email account per account holder. You can attach custom attributes for each account using Membership Profile. So your secondary email would simply be an attribute of the user's profile. Here is a great article [explaining](http://odetocode.com/Articles/440.aspx) how to do this.

Comment: Adding additional e-mails to the user's profile will only partially work. If a user can login via one of their multiple e-mails (as the author suggests), using a profile attribute will not prevent duplicate e-mails from getting into the system. It also will not work with any of the built-in membership providers as a means to authenticate.

Comment: That's what i want to do. That my users can login with multiple mails.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but not with any of the built-in membership providers. You will need to implement your own. Just know that your design will come down to ensuring that e-mail is unique in the table and is linked to a single user account (many-to-one). This will require a separate table in the database for the many e-mails a user may have.

Answer (score 0):

With the default membership providers, no. An email address maps to one user. You can however implement your own membership provider that will take care of this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd argue its not a job for the membership provider -- multiple email addresses smell like an application-layer concern.